# TypeError: Property 'locals' of object #<ServerResponse> is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using a github project to build a chat, but it is a bit outdated using express 3x.

The code tries to pass some data into the `req.locals` object, the commented out code is what I did but it does not save so it does not work in my `io.sockets.on('connection')` function.

I am trying to use that object to get some information about a room and the users inside.

```
/*
 * Enter to a room
 */

exports.enterRoom = function(req, res, room, users, rooms, status){
  res.locals.room = room;
  res.locals.rooms = rooms;
  res.locals.user.nickname = req.user.username;
  res.locals.user.provider = req.user.provider;
  res.locals.user.status = status;
  res.locals.users_list = users;

  // res.locals({
  //   room: room,
  //   rooms: rooms,
  //   user: {
  //     nickname: req.user.username,
  //     provider: req.user.provider,
  //     status: status
  //   },
  //   users_list: users
  // });

  console.log(res.locals);
  res.render('room');
};
```

Comment: You're getting the error because you're trying to invoke `res.locals` as a function: `res.locals()` when it's not. What are you trying to do?

Comment: https://github.com/rickyrauch/Balloons.IO/blob/master/utils.js line 167 I am just following this repo

Comment: It is working when I clone that but I am just trying to take parts from it inside my app, obviously that means that it has been defined as a function somewhere then.

Comment: res.locals is an object in the express version you are trying. Try to inspect express source : node_modules/express/lib/response.js

Comment: or try req.app.locals() fucntion

Comment: res.app.locals does expose settings and inside that there are functions within query parser

Comment: How did you send these data to socket connection ?

Comment: I am still trying to figure that out lol. I have everything ready except for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're trying to invoke `res.locals` as a function:

```
 res.locals() // this executes a function
```

when it appears that it's not. I don't know what you're trying to do but this is probably not the way to go about it.

Comment: I replied above it is from balloons.io repo I need to inspect it more and see if there is a function?

Comment: Maybe res.locals was a function inside express 3x?

Comment: Maybe it was. Are you trying to mix code from different versions of the repo? Then yeah, they could definitely have changed it.

Comment: Yeah thats what I am thinking, thats the one bad thing about node.js is all the version conflicts, but I will figure it out, thanks man